# Windows always move to main screen after restart, how to stop that

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors, LG22MK400A one of them is plug in to Interl(R) UHD Graphics 630 and second is plugged to NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 and I am working on windows 10 system.

My problem is that I have splitted windows apps on both monitors, but every single time when I unlock my screen all windows apps moving to my main monitor and I have to split them again. Is there any way to stop that? I found couple solution on internet but most of the time they suggest to upgrade the graphic cards drivers and that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused because your display is being uninstalled when you turn it off. This is common for DisplayPort and DVI devices. It will not happen for VGA (Sub-D) and HDMI. If your monitor is connected by either DP or DVI, see if you can change that.

Some monitors have a power saving option. Disabling this may prevent the monitor from being uninstalled when powered off.

Keep in mind that powersaving options in windows that turn off the screen also may do the very same thing. If you don't have a problem with leaving your monitors turned on, consider disabling putting the monitor to sleep and alternatively run a screensaver if you have an OLED panel.